# Wicket: Get DropDownChoice list item names from class variable names

Tags: java, wicket

I am developing a search functionality with wicket. The `DropDownChoice` class is used to select which field of the searched item is to be searched. How to accomplish this so that the drop down names would be taken directly from the searched class.

Let's say I have a class `FooBar` containing variables `foo` and `bar`. If I want to select which one is the select criteria field, how I can get the naming from a resource file giving values in my resource file like

```
   FooBar.foo="Search for foo"
   FooBar.bar="Search for bar"
```

The resource file should be like that, but how to wire this in java class side?

Comment: My aim is this: I have a selector (search foo or bar) and then search field that searches foos or bars depending on that selection. My issue is to how to map everything so, that only FooBar.name is required for i18n and search works like magic when everything is mapped correctly. Is there such a mapping? I am new to Wicket but I have read e.g. about PropertyModel and everything seems like this would be possible, but don't know how.

Comment: Nothing wicket specific. The only way I can see is using the java reflection api. See http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html for an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can get fields and its values like this

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class FooBar extends AbstractFooBar{
public String foo = "Search for foo";
public String bar = "Search for bar";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field[] fields = FooBar.class.getFields();
    // Field[] fields = AbstractFooBar.class.getFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        System.out.println(field.get(new Object()).toString());
    }
}
```

}
But as you can guess you cannot use any abstraction. Also all your fields must be public.

You can initialize your class by using resource file. You can pass fields by using IChoiceRenderer, to DropDownChoice after getting field with reflection.

Your DropDownChoice type can be Field and you can initialize it by giving field list. Then in your IChoiceRenderer you can get model object.

I hope it will help.